# How to increase/decrease number of child divs based on parent div height (%)

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div (parent) that needs to expand vertically with it's parent (grandparent) div that has a 30% height. Inside this parent div are small boxes (children) that will house pictures. The children are in rows of 3.
I would like there to be either 2 or 3 rows of children "depending" on the height of its parent div. How can I drop/add a row based on height of parent div?
Sorry, I don't know else to describe this.

Could this be done with css? I have tried overflow:hidden but I would prefer not to 'cut-off' the divs when browser decreases in height. (You will have to increase the height of viewing area to see what I mean.

If not, would there be a simple JavaScript solution?
Thanks!!

https://jsfiddle.net/lneale/mxggg847/17/

```
       body{
            background-color: gray;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #wrapper{
            width: 1000px;
            height: 30%;
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0 4px 4px 0;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
            #wrapper #rightBlock{
                width: 165px; /* needs to be fixed width */
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 6px;
                background-color: red;
                overflow: hidden;

            }
                #wrapper #rightBlock #rightBlockSearchBar{
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 30px;
                    margin-top: 10px;
                    background-color: #ccc;
                }
                #wrapper #rightBlock #rightBlockTitle{
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 30px;
                    margin-top: 10px;
                    background-color: #ccc;
                }

                #wrapper #rightBlock #rightBlockPicContainer{
                    width: 100%;
                    height: auto;
                    margin-top: 10px;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    overflow: auto;

                }
                    #wrapper #rightBlock #rightBlockPicContainer .rightBlockPics{
                        width: 38px;
                        height: 38px;
                        margin: 4px;
                        background-color: blue;
                        float: left;
                    }


            <body>
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="rightBlock">
                        <div id="rightBlockSearchBar">search bar</div>
                        <div id="rightBlockTitle">Title here</div>

                        <div id="rightBlockPicContainer">
                            <div class="rightBlockPics">
                            </div>
                            <div class="rightBlockPics">
                            </div>
                            <div class="rightBlockPics">
                            </div>
                            <div class="rightBlockPics">
                            </div>
                            <div class="rightBlockPics">
                            </div>
                            <div class="rightBlockPics">
                            </div>
                            <div class="rightBlockPics">
                            </div>
                            <div class="rightBlockPics">
                            </div>
                            <div class="rightBlockPics">
                            </div>
                            <div class="rightBlockPics">
                            </div>
                            <div class="rightBlockPics">
                            </div>
                            <div class="rightBlockPics">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
```

Comment: *"Is this possible with CSS?"*...NO...CSS is not a programming language and doesn't do *if/else* conditions.

Comment: @Paulie_D, thanks that's what i thought...hopefully there's a simple js solution